# Get a resource in rest API based on an alternative identificator

Tags: rest, api-design

What would be a rest API convention to get a resource based on a different identificator?

For example

```
GET
/resource/{id}

GET
/resource/{guid}
```

Since this could be considered as a dupliate resource and setting routes for this could be a problem, what is an alternative then would follow rest API guidelines?

Maybe

/resources/?guid={guid}

or

/resources/guid/{guid}

or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't normally duplicate an endpoint. The question would be:

> why does one client have an id while another has a guid?

what design choice allowed that to happen?

I would leave it as a single resource endpoint:

```
GET
/resource/{id}
```

so clients who access resources via their id will use the above endpoint. I'd allow clients who access resources via their guid to exchange what they have (guid) for what they need (id):

```
GET
/id/{guid}
```

The above returns a resource id for the given resource guid. The client can then call the main resource endpoint with the id they have just received:

```
GET
/resource/{id}
```

but ultimately I'd look into why some clients use a guid rather than an id and change that so all clients access the API in the same way.

Comment: I am not sure I follow you reasoning /id/{guid} vs /resource/{id}

Comment: @mko what poster is saying is that it is better to have an endpoint just to return the actual ID of the resource, rather than allow selection of the resource by two different path parameters, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

### Short answer

You could use both `/resource/{id}` and `/resource/{guid}`. Many frameworks support *regular expressions* for matching path parameter values.

### Long answer

REST is an *architectural style* and not a cookbook for designing URIs <sup>(see notes below)</sup>. It doesn't enforce any URI design and it's totally up to you to pick the URIs that better identify your resources.

What you should keep in mind is: it's perfectly fine to have [multiple mappings](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1) for the same entity. And *each mapping is a resource*, according to Fielding's dissertation:

> A resource is a conceptual mapping to a set of entities, not the entity that corresponds to the mapping at any particular point in time.

With that being said, if you are supporting [`DELETE`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.5), it's important to mention how it's supposed to work:

> [**4.3.5.  DELETE**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.5)
>
> The `DELETE` method requests that the origin server remove the association between the target resource and its current functionality.  In effect, this method is similar to the `rm` command in UNIX: it expresses a deletion operation on the URI mapping of the origin server rather than an expectation that the previously associated information be deleted. [...]

---

<sup>**Note 1:** The URI syntax is defined in the [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986). As general rule, the path is organized in *hierarchical* form (with segments separated by `/`) and can contain non-hierarchical data in the query component (starting with `?`).</sup>

<sup>**Note 2:** The REST architectural style is described in the [chapter 5](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) of Roy T. Fielding's dissertation and it defines a set of constraints that must be followed by the applications that follow such architecture. However it says nothing about what the URIs must be like.</sup>

<sup>**Note 3:** The *examples* of a [popular article](https://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html) written by Martin Fowler explaining a model defined by Leonard Richardson *suggest* a URI structure that looks friendly and easy to read.</sup>